# finding preceding xml node values by element name

Tags: xslt

I have a xml document in follwoing format:

```
<xml>
<dtd name="formslst">
<XMLDOC>
  <formslst>
    <forms>
      <h1>
        Level 1 heading 
        <h2>
          level 2 heading 
          <h3>
            level 3 heading
            <file>
              file1.pdf
              <title>
                title of file 1
                <file>
                  file2.pdf
                  <title>
                    title of file2
                       <h3> level 3 internal heading
                          <file> file2.pdf
                            <title>
                                title of file 3
                             </title>     
                           </file>
                        </h3>
                  </title>
              </file>
            </title>
          </file>
         </h3>
      </h2>
    </h1>
  </forms>
 </formslst>
</XMLDOC>
```

What i want is a xslt script so that if i pass a parameter as "file2.pdf" it should return me the title of file2.pdf as "title of file2" and the preceding h3 "**level 3 heading**" , h2 "level 2 heading" and h1 "level 1 heading" text values.

But if i pass file3.pdf then it should return me the title of file3.pdf as  "title of file 3" and the preceding h3 "**level 3 internal heading**" , h2 "level 2 heading" and h1 "level 1 heading" text values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match the relevant file by doing the following (where **$file** is the parameter containing your file name)

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//file[normalize-space(text()) = $file]"/>
```

Once the file is matched, the title is obtained quite simply

```
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(title/text())" />
```

From looking at the structure of the xml (which is not well-formed because you are missing closing **dtd** and **xml** tags), you don't actually want the preceding **h** elements, but ancestors

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::h1|ancestor::h2|ancestor::h3">
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:param name="file" select="'file2.pdf'"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//file[normalize-space(text()) = $file]"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="file">
      <title>
         <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(title/text())"/>
      </title>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::h1|ancestor::h2|ancestor::h3">
         <xsl:sort select="position()" order="descending"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="h1|h2|h3">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(text())"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is returned (Note you have two **file2.pdf** in your XML, I am assuming the second should be **file3.pdf**

```
<title>title of file2</title>
<h3>level 3 heading</h3>
<h2>level 2 heading</h2>
<h1>Level 1 heading</h1>
```

When the parameter is changed to **file3.pdf** the output is as follows:

```
<title>title of file 3</title>
<h3>level 3 internal heading</h3>
<h3>level 3 heading</h3>
<h2>level 2 heading</h2>
<h1>Level 1 heading</h1>
```